# How do I collect real time data of an external serial device in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, real-time, qt-creator

I am trying to collect real time data from an arduino (using the Qt class QSerialPort) and plot it in real time to a graph (using the class QCustomPlot). I am new to using serial devices so i'm not really sure which function to use in the QSerialPort class to collect the data.  Below is my current code of how I set up the serial:

```
QSerialPort serial;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    serial.setPortName("com4");
    serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

    setupRealtimeDataDemo(ui->customPlot);


}
```

...and here is my code for the real time slot data...

```
void MainWindow::realtimeDataSlot()
{
  // calculate two new data points:
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(4, 7, 0)
  double key = 0;
#else
  double key = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toMSecsSinceEpoch()/1000.0;
#endif
  static double lastPointKey = 0;
  if (key-lastPointKey > 0.01) // at most add point every 10 ms
  {
    double value0 = qSin(key); //sin(key*1.6+cos(key*1.7)*2)*10 + sin(key*1.2+0.56)*20 + 26;
    double value1 = qCos(key); //sin(key*1.3+cos(key*1.2)*1.2)*7 + sin(key*0.9+0.26)*24 + 26;
    // add data to lines:
    ui->customPlot->graph(0)->addData(key, value0);
    ui->customPlot->graph(1)->addData(key, value1);
    // set data of dots:
    ui->customPlot->graph(2)->clearData();
    ui->customPlot->graph(2)->addData(key, value0);
    ui->customPlot->graph(3)->clearData();
    ui->customPlot->graph(3)->addData(key, value1);
    // remove data of lines that's outside visible range:
    ui->customPlot->graph(0)->removeDataBefore(key-8);
    ui->customPlot->graph(1)->removeDataBefore(key-8);
    // rescale value (vertical) axis to fit the current data:
    ui->customPlot->graph(0)->rescaleValueAxis();
    ui->customPlot->graph(1)->rescaleValueAxis(true);
    lastPointKey = key;
  }
  // make key axis range scroll with the data (at a constant range size of 8):
  ui->customPlot->xAxis->setRange(key+0.25, 8, Qt::AlignRight);
  ui->customPlot->replot();

  // calculate frames per second:
  static double lastFpsKey;
  static int frameCount;
  ++frameCount;
  if (key-lastFpsKey > 2) // average fps over 2 seconds
  {
    ui->statusBar->showMessage(
          QString("%1 FPS, Total Data points: %2")
          .arg(frameCount/(key-lastFpsKey), 0, 'f', 0)
          .arg(ui->customPlot->graph(0)->data()->count()+ui->customPlot->graph(1)->data()->count())
          , 0);
    lastFpsKey = key;
    frameCount = 0;
  }
}
```

Any help on how to get data in real time and/or a better implementation would be appreciated.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the `readyRead` signal of the `QSerialPort` to a slot to read data whenever new data has arrived :

```
connect(serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readData()));
```

In `readData` you can call `readAll()` to read all available data to a `QByteArray` and pass the array to another function to plot :

```
void MainWindow::readData()
{
    QByteArray data = serial->readAll();

    plotMyData(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I [wrote a full demo application](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/QtSerial) that shows how to read data from the serial.

- **[main.cpp](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/blob/master/QtSerial/main.cpp)** specifies the settings required to open a valid connection, in this case to an **Arduino** device;
- **[serialportreader.h](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/blob/master/QtSerial/serialportreader.h)** implements the class that is responsible to read the data and print it to the console.

For some devices (like Arduino), it's essencial to invoke [`setDataTerminalReady(true);`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.1/qtserialport/qserialport.html#dataTerminalReady-prop) after `open()` has succeeded. So for those of you having trouble with [Terminal Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-terminal-example.html), remember to hack `void MainWindow::openSerialPort()` to:

```
void MainWindow::openSerialPort()
{
    SettingsDialog::Settings p = settings->settings();
    serial->setPortName(p.name);
    serial->setBaudRate(p.baudRate);
    serial->setDataBits(p.dataBits);
    serial->setParity(p.parity);
    serial->setStopBits(p.stopBits);
    serial->setFlowControl(p.flowControl);
    if (serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
            console->setEnabled(true);
            console->setLocalEchoEnabled(p.localEchoEnabled);
            ui->actionConnect->setEnabled(false);
            ui->actionDisconnect->setEnabled(true);
            ui->actionConfigure->setEnabled(false);
            ui->statusBar->showMessage(tr("Connected to %1 : %2, %3, %4, %5, %6")
                                       .arg(p.name).arg(p.stringBaudRate).arg(p.stringDataBits)
                                       .arg(p.stringParity).arg(p.stringStopBits).arg(p.stringFlowControl));

            // HACK
            serial->setDataTerminalReady(true);
    } else {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), serial->errorString());

        ui->statusBar->showMessage(tr("Open error"));
    }
}
```